# Subprocess doesn't find my file (file not found error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to use subprocess to call my current script as follows:

```
import subprocess as sb
current_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
sb.call(['python3', current_path])
```

However, I am ending up in a :

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Consider using [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to find out what path(s) are being accessed and the result obtained for each attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python3.exe` does not exist in any of the paths in your `PATH` environment variable. Use an absolute path to specify `python3.exe` instead, or use the `shell=True` argument:

```
sb.call(['python3', current_path], shell=True)
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I can run `python3 `command from the command line, so that should be mean it exists within my PATH variable right?

Comment: Is your `python3` command a shell alias, or an actual executable?

Comment: It can actually run python script(I am not sure what a shell alias is).
For example if I run from the cmd:

`python3 testing_keyboard_input.py` or  `python3.6 testing_keyboard_input.py`

It runs the particular script.

Comment: Okay, your update seems to work (with `shell = True`).  From the examples I have seen, they weren't using `shell = True`.  Is this a Windows nuance?

Comment: A shell alias is a shortcut in the command prompt that only the command prompt (shell) understands, usually done through the `doskey` command in Windows.

Comment: I don't think you actually have a `python3.exe` or `python3.6.exe` executable, but only an alias of `python3` and `python3.6` in shell that points to `python.exe` in a Python 3 directory, which is why without `shell=True`, the system cannot find the given command.